# Ignore dependencies with composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I need to install a new dependency in one old symfony 2.3 application. But seems that the previous installed packages are to old that I get the next error: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

This are my current dependencies:

```
    "php": ">=5.3.
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu":"dev-master",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"dev-master",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": ">=1.0.4",
    "tecnick.com/tcpdf": "6.0.023"
```

I need to add: "phpoffice/phpword": "v0.13.*" that require zend framework's packages.

There is any way of install my new dependencie without affect the already installed packages?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `composer why-not "phpoffice/phpword"`, you may get additional clarity as to what the problem is, and start to work around it by updating some packages to newer versions that can work together.